# history of strings for musical instruments

Tags: discussion

Is a question about the specific history of metallic instrument strings appropriate here? I see in the Help Tour that "we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about music ... history", but am a little concerned that the particularity of my question might make it inappropriate.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean the history of making strings out of metal, not the provenance of a particular set of strings, right? The latter would probably be too specific!

Comment: @DanHulme, yes, that's it; specific to metallic strings (as opposed to gut, silk, whatever).

Comment: Specific questions are generally exactly what we want, as long as they are not extremely _localized_ (as in Dan's example).  "The history of metal strings" seems pretty broad to me, so I would actually lean towards making it more specific.

Comment: @MatthewRead, Thanks for your comment. I've found a history that answered my question. Not very well, but well enough.